# Ansible output extract package version using jq

Tags: json, ansible, jq

I have below json output from ansible, I want to parse this file using `jq`.  I want to match packages name `GeoIP` and print version number.

How can I use `jq` to get this version number for matching package name? looking output like this

```
"GeoIP","1.5.0"
```

**sample ansible output**

```
{
    "ansible_facts.packages": {
        "GConf2": [
            {
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "epoch": null,
                "name": "GConf2",
                "release": "8.el7",
                "source": "rpm",
                "version": "3.2.6"
            }
        ],
        "GeoIP": [
            {
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "epoch": null,
                "name": "GeoIP",
                "release": "14.el7",
                "source": "rpm",
                "version": "1.5.0"
            }
        ],
        "ImageMagick": [
            {
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "epoch": null,
                "name": "ImageMagick",
                "release": "18.el7",
                "source": "rpm",
                "version": "6.7.8.9"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the source valid json by removing the comma in the third to last row.

With that done, we can start at the end and work back. The desired output can be produced using jq's @csv format. That, in turn, requires that the output is in an array. (See the section of the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) titled "Format strings and escaping".) So we need to get the data to look like this.

```
jq -r '["GeoIP","1.5.0"] | @csv'
```

One way to do that is to put each item in its own array and add the arrays together. (See [the section](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) titled "Addition".)

```
jq -r '["GeoIP"] + [.[] | .GeoIP[].version] | @csv'
```

Since `map(x)` is defined as `[.[] | x]`, you can say this instead.

```
jq -r '["GeoIP"] + map(.GeoIP[].version) | @csv'
```

You can use a variable to specify the package name you want like this.

```
jq -r --arg "package" "GeoIP" '[$package] + map(.[$package][].version) | @csv'
```

**Update**

My original solution has unnecessary steps. The array can be made like this.

```
jq -r '[ "GeoIP", .[].GeoIP[].version ] | @csv'
```

Or, using a variable

```
jq -r --arg "package" "GeoIP" '[$package,(.[] | .[$package][].version)]| @csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get a loop over all key-values attributes in the `ansible_facts.packages`, so it's recommended to use a Bash loop to iterate over it. Also the sample contents of the JSON you provided don't compile, I removed the comma 3 rows from the end.

You need one jq to get all the keys of the `ansible_facts.packages` and then in each iteration to get the version of the given key (package).

To get all the keys:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-30 tmp]$ cat file.json | jq '."ansible_facts.packages" | keys[]'
"GConf2"
"GeoIP"
"ImageMagick"
[http_offline@greenhat-30 tmp]$
```

Loop:

```
for package in `cat file.json | jq '."ansible_facts.packages" | keys[]'`
do
VERSION=`cat file.json | jq ".\"ansible_facts.packages\".$package[0].version"`
echo "$package,$VERSION"
done
```

Sample run:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-30 tmp]$ for package in `cat file.json | jq '."ansible_facts.packages" | keys[]'`
> do
> VERSION=`cat file.json | jq ".\"ansible_facts.packages\".$package[0].version"`
> echo "$package,$VERSION"
> done
"GConf2","3.2.6"
"GeoIP","1.5.0"
"ImageMagick","6.7.8.9"
[http_offline@greenhat-30 tmp]$
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"How can I use jq to get the version number for matching package name?"*

A: Try the script below

```
$ cat print-version.sh
#!/bin/sh
cat output.json | jq ".ansible_facts.packages.$1 | .[].version"
```

For example

```
$ print-version.sh GeoIP
"1.5.0"
```

---

Improved version of the script

Quoting the comment: *`"Using the shell's string interpolation as done here is risky and generally regarded as an "anti-pattern". – peak"`*

The improved script below does the job

```
$ cat print-version.sh
#!/bin/sh
cat output.json | jq ".ansible_facts.packages.$1[].version"
```

---

output.json

```
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "packages": {
            "GConf2": [
                {
                    "arch": "x86_64",
                    "epoch": null,
                    "name": "GConf2",
                    "release": "8.el7",
                    "source": "rpm",
                    "version": "3.2.6"
                }
            ],
            "GeoIP": [
                {
                    "arch": "x86_64",
                    "epoch": null,
                    "name": "GeoIP",
                    "release": "14.el7",
                    "source": "rpm",
                    "version": "1.5.0"
                }
            ],
            "ImageMagick": [
                {
                    "arch": "x86_64",
                    "epoch": null,
                    "name": "ImageMagick",
                    "release": "18.el7",
                    "source": "rpm",
                    "version": "6.7.8.9"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: got this error `./print-version.sh GeoIP
jq: error (at <stdin>:34): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

Comment: *`"JSON you provided doesn't compile. Remove the comma 3 rows from the end."`* ilias-sp already told you so.

Comment: I removed the comma, still getting the same error message. same input file this one works `cat output.json | jq -r --arg "package" "GeoIP" '[$package,(.[] | .[$package][].version)]| @csv'`

Comment: I've updated my answer with output.json used in the example. Make your choice.

Comment: Using the shell's string interpolation as done here is risky and generally regarded as an "anti-pattern".

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the answer with the fixed version of the script.